# Implication of difference in degrees of freedom on t-test results

Tags: t-test, degrees-of-freedom

I'm trying to figure out the practical meaning of less degrees of freedom regarding the results of t-test results. For example: If I have two dependent samples and would like to compare their means using a t-test. If I use both tests for dependent and independent samples I will have more degrees of freedom in the dependent test (i.e. for unknown mean and variance independent sample will have *n-2* df, and the dependent *n-1*).

Assuming that my basic knowledge is valid and the description above is correct, what will be the impact of using each test with less or more *df* on the results (p-values, probability to receive false positive/negative)?

Does any of this make sense?

Comment: The same t-value with more df will have a lower p value. But this is trivial compared to gains made by using the dependence.

Comment: @PeterFlom. Thank you. So as far as I understand there is no practical significance for the number of degrees of freedom in the context that I've described above. Is that right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "practical significance". The df will affect the p-value.